# Bootstrap responsive table active tab with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using Bootstrap's responsive table:

```
<ul class='nav nav-tabs first-table'>
<li><a href='#1' data-toggle='tab'>Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href='#2' data-toggle='tab'>Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href='#3' data-toggle='tab'>Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class='tab-content margin-bottom'>
```

To get the first tab to be active on page load, I am using some script from JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.first-table a:first').tab('show');
});
```

But I also use Ajax to update the table dynamically when the user clicks the 'next' or 'prev' button, and whenever that happens, I re-run the script to keep the first tab active:

```
$('.first-table a:first').tab('show');
```

However, if the user has already switched tabs on the table before clicking 'next' or 'prev', the Ajax will bring the user back to the first tab. Is there a way to create a global variable that will keep the track of whichever tab is currently active, and somehow feed that into the Ajax script? I also tried changing "a:first'" to "a:second'" to see if I could change the default active tab, but that also didn't work either.

Sorry if this is a long-winded way to ask a very simple question. I'm new to a lot of this and have been having a hard time.

Comment: Create a fiddle. That will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: I played around with fiddle but a lot of my code is in PHP and fiddle doesn't seem to support PHP. Is there any specific area of the code I can paste that would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well do this.

First save the default value of the tab in a variable:

```
var selected='#1'; //#1 is the 'href' of your tab's anchor tag
```

Then on click of any tab, save the *href* into the variable:

```
$('.first-table a').on('click',function(){
    selected = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

And finally, one the AJAX response, you can do:

```
$('.first-table a[href="'+selected+'"]').tab('show');
```

Here's a demo with the 'Reset' button acting as your AJAX and how you can restore the tabs after being resetted.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2S5QW/)**

Comment: Just want to say thanks again! This was eye opening and really helpful!

Comment: Say I have two identical tables on the same page and want to remember both tabs. Would there be a way to do this?